# Is there a difference between Google Place and Google Location

Tags: android, location, google-places-api

Can somebody explain the difference between Google Place and Google Location to me?

Also, it seems possible to convert a Place to a Location via Latitude and Longitude, but not the other way round?

basically i'm trying to setup a PlaceAutoComplete but want it to be populated with current location automatically - i'm not able to and hence am ending up using Location for this -- driving me nuts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google places shows you things around you. For example restaurants, the empire state building or whatever is around in your current location. Therefore you can not convert a location to a place, because where someone is right now is not really a place, for example you are standing on a road (there is nothing special).

A location simply describes where something is, it could be a place, too, by using longitudes and latitudes.

Comment: PlacePicker however seems to be able to be used to pick any "Location" too -- that's the confusing part...for example you could drop it in the middle of nowhere and it just uses an approximate Place (e.g the city to which that "place" belongs"

Comment: Thats right, even so I can hardly imagine in which scenario this makes sense, because I don't know how to pick only special places like gas stations...

Answer (score 0):

Google Location gives the location of the phone whereas google place gives the locations of places such as businesses, addresses, points of interests.

Seems like to do you what you want you need to first get the location in lat from the Google location then use Places API to [Bias results to a specific region][1] using the lat and long.

Something like this:

`autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
        new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
        new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596)));`

Comment: This does not actually populate the autocompleteFragment location